# How to handle pop up in mobile automation

Tags: karate, bdd

Using Karate framework, I'm working on mobile scenario automation. I am unable to handle an application pop up (screenshot attached). I want to click on OK option on this pop up, but it's not working. I have tried with setting below capabilities.

```
   "autoAcceptAlerts" : true
   "autoGrantPermissions" : true
```

Please let me know is there a way in karate framework to handle these pop ups?

[image]

[image: mobile snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Since these look like custom alerts, you could try [mobile commands in appium](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#mobile-acceptalert) to do this.

```
* driver.script("mobile: acceptAlert", { "buttonLabel" : "OK"})
```